# Simultaneously partitioning two ranges of elements the same way in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Is there a C++ standard method for partitioning two ranges of elements simultaneously and partitioning the second range of elements according to the partitioning of the first range of elements? Like the `std::partition`, the partitioning operates on one range of elements and the other range of elements is partitioned the same way. Or is there an efficient way of doing this without having to copy and adapt the `std::partition` method and without zipping the two ranges?

Example:

```
[a, b, c, d, e] -> [a, c, e, b, d]
[f, g, h, i, j] -> [f, h, j, g, i]
```

Comment: There is no sequence operation in C++11 that does this directly. You'll have to make something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have the time to code this in detail right now, I have the following idea. From what I can see in the docs for `std::{stable_}partition`, it does in no way report the swaps it performs to the client. Thus, you can't extract that information and apply it to the second range. Anything relying on comparing and manually reordering the elements would probably be too slow.

**Approach 1 (simpler)**
A way simpler implementation occurred to me. Above I state that we can't get the swaps out of `std::partition`. Well, I think we can, at the cost of using some additional memory.

1. Turn the leading vector (the one partition is based one) into a `std::vector<std::pair<T, int>>`.
2. At the start, each tag equals the element position in the vector.
3. Call `std::partition` with a predicate that only takes into account `std::pair::first()` (i.e. `T`).
4. After `std::partition` exits, reorder the second vector as follows: the tag values in the leading vector are the element indexes in the second vector, while the element indexes of the leading vector are the new element positions. Thus, a new ordering is known, and we can reorder the second vector accordingly by performing swaps smartly.

This approach takes additional memory `O(n)` multiplied by `sizeof` an `int` or say a `char` for a short input vector. But, it's easy to implement: only one custom predicate and one loop of swaps.

**Approach 2 (more complicated)**

Based on the same assumption that swaps aren't visible from the outside, we can arrive to a solution as follows:

1. "glue" the two ranges together into a single linear data structure (possibly by defining a proxy adapter class)
2. launch `std::partition` on that, with a custom predicate, that would compare the first elements in the "zipped" DS (along the lines of `pair::first()`), but since the two arrays are now unified by the means of an adapter, the swaps would occur on the elements in both arrays
3. remove the temporary DS if required ("un-glue" the two arrays)

**Edit:** Given that `std::partition` uses `std::swap`, a key part of this approach will be to redefine `std::swap` for your pair element type (is this still called "overload" for templates?). As far as I can see, this function can be overloaded for custom types, which proves that it is possible to construct an algorithm like described in **approach 2** using `std::partition`, but re-defining both the swap function and the comparison predicate.

Comment: This is a little like a Schwartzian transform: Transform `[f,g,h...]` into `[a,b,c...]`. Sort that to get `[a,c,e...]` and transform back again to get `[f,h,j...]`

Comment: @quamrana actually I've found a way simpler approach, see above. This is the first time I hear about the Schwartzian transform, thank you, will read up.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that your idea of using `std::pair` is equivalent to the pair of transforms either side of the sort.